# Is System.Messaging.dll not available in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, msmq, system.messaging

I have a C# Publisher-Subscriber project intended to make use of the `MSMQ service` in Windows. The code was developed in `.Net Framework 4`. I want to run it in `.Net Core`. But I am getting the error

> "The type or namespace name "Messaging" donot exist in the namespace System".

Does .Net Core support MSMQ?

Does .Net Core has a corresponding `System.Messaging.dll` which appears to be missing.?

Comment: Since you don't need cross platform support (MSMQ is microsoft-only) - you probably won't benefit from moving to .net core anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx) is not platform independent and therfore not supported by .Net Core.

Comment: MSMQ may not be, but .net core itself is platform independent. .net core processes running on any environment should be able to connect and use MSMQ instances running on Windows, so this should not be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Even though MSMQ is Windows only, the future even on Windows is .NET Core and .NET Framework basically is end-of-life.

Currently the only way to use MSMQ on .NET Core is via the following package:

- https://github.com/krazure/Experimental.System.Messaging

Comment: There's another port to.NET CORE for MSMQ here https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSMQ.Messaging/, which I found while reading through all the .NET CORE github comments!